# minimization of L^2 norm of the second derivative of a probability density

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

I have a question:

Let $\rho$ denote a probability density function defined on $[0,1]$. It is twice-differentiable and has a continuous second derivative. Denote by $M$ the set of all such functions $\rho$ satisfying $\rho(0)=\rho(1)=0$. Define

$$L(\rho)= \sqrt{\int_0^1 \rho''(x)^2dx}$$

What is the minimizer?

If $\rho^{\ast}$ is the minimizer, then for any $\rho\in M$ and any $\lambda\in[0,1]$, we have

$$f(0)\leq f(\lambda), \ \ \forall\lambda\in[0,1]$$

where $f(\lambda):=L^2((1-\lambda)\rho^{\ast}+\lambda\rho)$. Then a little calculus gives

$$f'(0)=2\int_0^1(\rho''-\rho''^{\ast})\rho''^{\ast}\geq 0$$

But I don't know how to continue from this inequality, could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One wants to minimize the functional $U(\varrho)=\int_0^1(\varrho'')^2$ under the constraints that
$\varrho(0)=0$, $\varrho(1)=0$, $\int_0^1\varrho=1$. Assume that $\varrho$ is a minimizer, then for every $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(0)=0$, $\sigma(1)=0$, $\int_0^1\sigma=0$, one knows that $U(\varrho+t\sigma)\geqslant U(\varrho)$, for every $|t|$ small enough. Thus,
$$
\langle\nabla U(\varrho),\sigma\rangle=0.
$$
If $\varrho$ is regular enough,
$$
\langle\nabla U(\varrho),\sigma\rangle=2\int_0^1\varrho''\sigma''=2\left[\varrho''\sigma'-\varrho^{(3)}\sigma\right]_0^1+2\int_0^1\varrho^{(4)}\sigma,
$$
thus,
$$
\varrho''(1)\sigma'(1)-\varrho''(0)\sigma'(0)+\int_0^1\varrho^{(4)}\sigma=0.
$$
If $\varrho^{(4)}$ is not constant, one can find $x\ne y$ such that $\varrho^{(4)}(x)\ne\varrho^{(4)}(y)$, and $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(0)=0$, $\sigma(1)=0$, $\int_0^1\sigma=0$, $\sigma'(0)=0$, $\sigma'(1)=0$, nonzero in neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ only and of opposite signs on these two neighborhoods. Then $\sigma$ is admissible and contradicts the identity above.

Hence $\varrho^{(4)}$ is constant. A similar reasoning shows that $\varrho'(0)=\varrho'(1)=0$. Thus, there exists some positive constant $c$ such that $\varrho(x)=cx^2(1-x)^2$, and the normalizing condition $\int_0^1\varrho=1$ shows that $c=30$.

All the above is a way to guess the minimizer. Conversely, starting from $\varrho:x\mapsto30x^2(1-x)^2$, one checks that, for every $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(0)=0$, $\sigma(1)=0$, $\int_0^1\sigma=0$, $\sigma'(0)=0$, $\sigma'(1)=0$, 
$$
U(\varrho+t\sigma)=U(\varrho)+t^2U(\sigma)\geqslant U(\varrho).
$$
These conditions on $\sigma$ describe a neighborhood of $\varrho$ in $M$ hence $\varrho$ is indeed a local minimum of $U$ on $M$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think there is a trouble. We focus the minimization on the positive functions, but we can guarantee the positivity of the $U(\rho+t\sigma)$

Comment: The conditions at the end (including $\sigma'(0)=\sigma'(1)=0$) imply that $\varrho+t\sigma$ is positive on $(0,1)$ for $t$ small enough (hence $\varrho+t\sigma$ is in $M$). This is because $\varrho''(0)$ and $\varrho''(1)$ are positive and one considers $\sigma$s such that $\sigma''(0)$ and $\sigma''(1)$ are finite.

Comment: Thanks Did for his answer and now I have another question: sinc we have found a minimizer that is a polynomial of degree 4,  can we find all minimizers of class $\mathcal{C}^2$?

Comment: Perhaps there exists an even better function, $\rho$, for which $\rho^{(3)}$ and $\rho^{(4)}$ do not exist?

Comment: As explained in the answer, what this proves is: (1) there exists an explicit function $\varrho$ (which happens to be smooth) such that $U$ is minimal at $\varrho$ in a neighborhood of $\varrho$, (2) this $\varrho$ is the only $C^4$ minimizer. Nothing else.